# App moves off the screen

Tags: android, screen, listadapter

I am developing an app for android and have run into a slight problem. I have an activity with horizontal orientation with four tabs and each tab calls a seperate listadapter. The problem is when I turn the screen off then back on, the whole screen moves down. Has anyone had a similar problem and if so, how did you fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem on the motorola xoom , where the gridview went outside the screen because of the system bar. i don't know what is the best fix for this , but what i did is to allow the window to be outside of it limit.
the weird thing was that i had those problems only on motorola xoom , and only on an activity with a gridview . can you please give some more details?

try this and tell me if it helped (put it on the onCreate method of the activity) :

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

the bad thing is that on amazon kindle fire it caused a bug that the bottom side of the screen was hidden because of the kindle's system bar . on all of the other devices i used, it worked just fine.